# error in connecting to db

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have started using PDO in php for the first time.

Here is my code:

```
$host="localhost";
$dbname="meme";
$user="root";
$pass="dream";

global $dbh;
try 
{ 
    //dbh : Database Handle  
    $dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname,$user,$pass");  
}  
catch(PDOException $e)
{  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'
(using password: NO)
```

I guess its a common error as I could get a number of related posts on both Google and StackOverflow  but I fail to correct it maybe because of my limited knowledge in  the field. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$dbh= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
```

You have quoted the DSN, username, and password altogether. This way those 3 parameters are actually only one parameter. Therefore from PDO' constructors POV, you are not passing username, and password.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to MySQL's permission system. You should explicitly grant permissions to `@localhost` (using named socket) instead of the default `@%` (using network socket):

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO `www-data`@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Btw, I've assumed that you made a typo in your pastie. The quote should go until just before `,$user,$pass);`

Comment: @Shagun No, you type this in MySQL itself.

Comment: It might be the case, but from the error he is receiving, I think the problem is the way he quoted  all parameters. Hence the "(using password: NO)".

Comment: @racetrack I didn't check his code before, so I initially went purely on the error shown (which is a likely scenario nonetheless) :)